# É possível retirar a primeira sequencia da ultima letra da regex?

Tags: php, regex

Preciso de ajuda em algo bem específico, que envolve boa interpretação, é o seguinte, preciso que ao informar uma palavra na `regex` exemplo `nt` a ultima letra que seria `t` fosse estendida até a primeira sequencia de `t's` e parasse, exemplo...

**em**

```
$txt = "nttttouterttt";

echo preg_replace('/nt/', '', $txt);

saida: tttouterttt
```

**resultado esperado**

```
$txt = "nttttouterttt";

echo preg_replace('/nt/', '', $txt);

saida: outerttt
```

**caso a próxima letra não fora 't', não continua a sequencia**

```
$txt = "ntptttouterttt";

echo preg_replace('/nt/', '', $txt);

saida: ptttouterttt
```

`nt` é removido, mas gostaria de remover o `nt>ttt<` inteiro, restando apenas `outerttt`, caso a string fora `ntptttouterttt` ele retiraria só o nt, é possível? haveria outro método? aceito sugestões e material...

Comment: por favor de alguns exemplos de entrada e suas respectivas saídas para que possamos analisar sua lógica em ação, fica mais fácil entregar algo correto ;)

Comment: @Paz, realmente, já editei.

Comment: No primeiro caso, ao invés de `nt`, já tentou usar o `n[t]+`? Ou `n[t]*`? Em que usa o Quantificador `+`, que irá corresponder entre uma e ilimitadas vezes o operador t ou `*` que corresponde de zero a ilimitadas vezes.

Comment: Cara sério que isso? testei aqui e me parece que deu certo, pensei que seria maior complicação kk, muito obrigado vei...

Comment: @danieltakeshi posta como resposta pro Felipe aceitar, assim se outras pessoas tiverem a mesma dúvida e chegarem aqui via pesquisa conseguem ver mais fácil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Regex utilizada é a `nt+` ou a `nt*`, com a [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dlfOZY/1).

Em que o site Regex101 pode ser usado para testar Regexes, muito usado por causa das cores de formatação, design simples e facilidade de utilização.

#### Explicação

`nt+` Valida a parte da String que inicia com `n` e possui pelo menos um `t` a infinitos

- `n` - Corresponde literalmente o caractere *n*
- `t` - Corresponde literalmente o caracter *t*.
- `+` - Quantificador que corresponde de uma a ilimitadas vezes, quantas vezes for possível (*greedy*).

`nt*` Valida a parte da String que inicia com `n` e não necessariamente possui `t` a infinitos `t`

- `n` - Corresponde literalmente o caractere *n*
- `t` - Corresponde literalmente o caracter *t*.
- `*` - Quantificador que corresponde de zero a ilimitadas vezes, quantas vezes for possível (*greedy*).

Comment: Os colchetes foram desnecessários. Você poderia quantificar apenas `t` sem precisar colocá-lo numa seleção. As regex `nt+` e `nt*` são equivalentes a o que você escreveu

Comment: Verdade, vou editar. Foi costume de colocar mais coisas e de deixar evidente o que está sendo quantificado.

Comment: Resposta concisa e atende perfeitamente aos requisitos +1